# Why writing anything after the fileName of a #include directive does't give any errors in a C program?

Tags: c, filenames

Why doesn't writing anything after the `fileName` of a `#include` directive give any errors in a C program?

```
#include <fileName.h> we can write anything in here and it will not give an error after program compilation
main() {
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

heres another example:

```
#include "fileName.h" we can write here anything and its fine this will not give an error after compilation
main() {
  printf("Hello World");
}
```

Reading the Documentation didn't help please if you find anything about this behavior from the **C specification** lemme know heres the link [C Documentation](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)

Comment: See 6.10.2.4 in the link you gave.

Comment: ok i will thank you very much

Comment: theres no **6.10.2.4** i didnt get searching the Documentation

Comment: @Kevin: Direct link to the citation: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p4

Comment: @Fred Larson thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any text after the included file.

Section 6.10.2 of the C standard regarding `#include` states:

> *2* A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header
>   identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the `<` and `>`
>   delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire
>   contents of the header.  How the places are specified or the header
>   identified is implementation-defined.
>
> *3* A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the
>   source file identified by  the  specified  sequence  between  the `"`
>   delimiters.   The named  source  file  is  searched for in an
>   implementation-defined manner.  If this search is not supported, or if
>   the searchfails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>
> ```
> # include <h-char-sequence> new-line
> ```
>
> with  the  identical  contained  sequence 
>   (including `>` characters,  if  any)  from  the  original directive.
>
> *4* A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include pp-tokens  new-line
> ```
>
> (that  does  not  match  one  of  the  two  previous  forms)  is 
>   permitted.   The  preprocessing tokens  after `include` in  the 
>   directive  are  processed  just  as  in  normal  text.   (Each
>   identifier  currently  defined  as  a  macro  name  is  replaced  by 
>   its  replacement  list  of preprocessing  tokens.)   The directive 
>   resulting  after  all  replacements  shall  match  one  of the  two 
>   previous  forms. The  method  by  which  a  sequence  of 
>   preprocessing  tokens between a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair
>   or a pair of"characters is combined into a single header name
>   preprocessing token is implementation-defined.

None of these forms allows for text after the included filename.  In fact, both gcc and MSVC issue warnings in this case.

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> bogus text

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.8.5 outputs:

```
x1.c:1:20: warning: extra tokens at end of #include directive [enabled by default]
 #include <stdio.h> bogus text
                    ^
```

And MSVC 2015 outputs:

```
x1.c
x1.c(1): warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
```

Comment: Yes but my compiler didn't warn me about this im using `gcc`